# Using secrets module with PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, compatibility

I'm using PyGame, so I backdated to Python 3.2. I would like to use a number generator that's cryptographically secure in my game, because I can. I tried importing the secrets module, but it's not in the 3.2 Python version.

How do I use both the PyGame and secrets modules in the same program? Maybe by scripting a switch in Python versions in a function?

Comment: "I'm using PyGame, so I backdated to Python 3.2" - what? Why? Get a modern Python version.

Comment: Can PyGame be used in the latest Python version?

Comment: The installers still say 3.1 or 3.2, but PyGame is compatible with more recent versions. (I don't know if the *installers* are, but PyGame is.)

Comment: "Yes. Pygame 1.9.2 supports Python 3.2 and up. Only the orphaned _movie module (not built by default) does not." from https://www.pygame.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestion

Comment: The secrets module was added in Python 3.6. You can just `pip install pygame` for Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I know it says python 3.2 on the packages but I am currently running python 3.6 and it works fine. Just download python 3.6 and install pygame.